# Как вернуть определенный объект из метода?

Tags: android, kotlin

В одном из классов происходит вызов метода другого класса **RequestInterface**

```
val requestInterface = RequestInterface.getRetrofitBuild(ExampleApi::class.java)
```

Где находится метод *getRetrofitBuild*, который возвращая необходимый объект.

```
fun getRetrofitBuild(exampleApi : ExampleApi): ExampleApi {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseDomain)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build().create(exampleApi::class)
}
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, что в этом методе можно было передевать не только **ExampleApi**, но и другие объекты, например, **SimpleApi**?

```
interface ExampleApi { 
    @GET("getItems?") 
    fun getAllItems(@Query("type") type: String): Observable<List<Items>> }

interface SimpleApi { 
    @GET("getItems?") 
    fun getAllItems(@Query("lang") language: String): Observable<List<Items>> 
}
```

Comment: Покажите эти `*Api` классы-то.

Comment: Сделал правку, добавив классы

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать такой вариант: 


`inline fun <reified T : Any> getRetrofitBuild(baseDomain: String = Constants.BASE_DOMAIN) : T {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseDomain)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(T::class.java)
    }`


Только в этом вариант нельзя использовать приватные переменные, только публичные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дженерики вам помогут. Быстрый набросок:

```
fun <T> getRetrofitService(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseDomain)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(clazz)
}
```

Метод возвращает сервис реторфита, не билдер. Поэтому я его переименовал.